# Count and Display number of blank lines using Bash

Tags: bash, grep

We have to send an error message when a file contains more then 21 blank lines in a row.  Blank can include whitespace.
The current solution stopped working when we switched to a new server.  It's possible that it never worked, but I've been tasked with making sure that the various scripts work.  This script is written in Bash, so ideally a solution will work with Bash, otherwise, I'd have to switch within the script, and that would be an issue, I think.

The error message also has to include the lines before and after the blank lines.

This is what was used before:
grep to count number of issues (if greater than 0, it sends an e-mail):

```
grep -nc $'[\x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a]' filename
```

To show the problem lines (displayed in e-mail)

```
grep -n $'[\x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a]' filename
```

Again, I don't know if this ever worked.  But, I need to make it work.
I've tried using this, which works for the count... but it won't work if there is whitespace, and I can't get the before/after lines to work with it.

```
grep -czoP '\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n' filename
```

Comment: `grep -n $'[\x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a...` won't work, since with the `$'...'` quotes, the shell passes hard newlines to grep, and grep uses them to separate patterns. There'll be a bunch of empty lines in the pattern argument, and they'll match on each and every line. Actually grep might just immediately complain about the pattern `[` not being valid.

Comment: With `grep -zP`, the `\n` works to look for a newline, but you can't usefully get context lines, since now the input is taken as NUL-separated strings, not newline-separated lines. What ever comes after the next newline is part of the same input "line".

Answer (score 3):

Using an `awk` script to detect whether the file has more than a certain number of lines that are either empty or that only contain blanks (spaces and/or tabs):

```bsh
if ! awk -v max=21 '/^[[:blank:]]*$/ { if (++count >= max) exit 1; next } { count = 0 }'
then
    echo 'file contains 21 or more consecutive blank lines'
else
    echo 'file contains no more than consecutive 20 blank lines'
fi <file
```

This matches the regular expression `^[[:blank:]]*$` against each line in the input file in turn.  The expression will match empty lines and lines that only contain spaces and/or tabs.  If the expression matches, a counter is incremented.  If the counter reaches the given maximum (the `max` variable, set on the command line), the script terminates with a non-zero exit status.  If the expression does not match, the counter is reset to zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression to search for more complex matches. In your case you need to add to each line that you accept any number (0 or more) of whitespace characters (I truncated it to three lines instead of 21):

```
grep -czP '[ ]*\n[ ]*\n[ ]*\n' filename
```

Comment: Why are you using `-P`? And `-o` is surely non-effective with `-c`?

Comment: I'm just wondering because it doesn't seem to be doing what's being asked for when testing.

Comment: On GNU grep -P means --perl-regexp. This is required to have the pattern [ ]* to function; which POSIX do you use?

Comment: I'm not certain why it needs czoP, but it doesn't find anything without the P.
This fixed my whitespace issue.  Thank you for that.
But, it doesn't solve the second question on finding the line before and after the blank lines.

Comment: @ they: You are right that -o and -c are not going together, I corrected the post

Comment: `[ ]*` is a POSIX basic regular expression (the same as `\ *`). You may need `-P` to match `\n` as newline.

Comment: A sparse version checking for 20+ empty lines which includes any whitespace chacacter could look like this `grep -czP '([[:space:]]*\n){20}' filename`

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
while read -r line; do
    # add +1 every time the line is empty, reset the count if line contains anything
    [[ -z $line ]] && i=$((i+1)) || i=0

    if [[ $i -ge 20 ]]; then
        # Do the error handeling in this block
        echo "ERROR: 20+ empty consecutive lines"
        break # stop reading file by breaking the loop
    fi
done <file
```

This reply is edited, original missed a crieria.

Comment: ah right, sorry, the `read` removes them.

Answer (score 0):

Going back to your question, I agree the `awk` is more suitable for that task. Here you are an `awk` script, to print the lines preceding and folowing those blank lines:

```
awk 'BEGIN{AA="";BB="";CC=0}{LST=CC;if(CC==0){BB=AA};AA=$0;if($0 ~ "^[[:space:]]*$"){CC++}else{CC=0;if(LST>21){print "Error:\n"BB"\n"LST" free, to:\n"AA"\n\n"}}}' searched.txt
```

You can save the awk's commands in a file what can be helpful for debugging. Such file could look like:

```
BEGIN{AA="";BB="";CC=0}
{ LST=CC;if(CC==0){BB=AA};AA=$0;
  if( $0 ~ "^[[:space:]]*$") { CC++ } 
  else { CC=0; 
         if(LST>21) {print "Error:\n"BB"\n"LST" free, to:\n"AA"\n"}};
}
```

and the bash command shoud be:

```
awk -f command.file searched.txt
```

This is an example, and it suppose that there exist at least one line before and one line after the blank space. You may tune up this example for the case the `searched.txt` does contain no other line than blank one (with spaces). Or the `searched.txt` begins with more than 21 blank lines or ends with more than 21 blank lines.

Comment: Thanks, this works for the second part.